# How to open the TWA application on the links with my URL?

Tags: android, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, twa

I have a TWA application. When I receive FCM push notifications, with a link to my PWA site, clicking on them opens the Chrome browser. But I need all the links to my site to open my TWA application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, just add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>
   ...
    <meta-data
        android:name="cros_web_alternative"
        android:value="https://www.example.com/" /> 
   ...
</application>
```

Comment: Did you really try this on Android? The comment in Google's demo project (https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/blob/78ea4fe31ca65b02d662a6eace2e35af3d129c9f/app/build.gradle) says "The URL that will be opened as a Desktop PWA when the TWA is installed and run on ChromeOS." I wonder why it should have any effect on Android.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to add assets links to your site

At {your-domain}/.well-known/assetlinks.json

and assetlinks.json you will get while creating TWA as-

go to tools(android studio)->App Links Assistant->Associate Website(Open digital Assets files link generator)

there you can generate assetslinks for your site after filling relevant information.

To get more info follow:
https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started